# Insert parameters to python program from shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to execute my python program from shell script so that the print commands in my python program will be exposed for reading from another program.
the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [ $# -gt 2 ];then
    echo "Usage: $0 APK <duration in seconds>"
    exit 1;
fi

printf "$(python '/root/Desktop/DroidBox_4.1.1/scripts/droidbox.py' $1 $2 -c 'import sys; exec sys.stdin.read()')"
```

My python program should get the parametrs $1 and $2 but it doesn't recognize those as parametrs but taking -c and the command after it as the parametrs.

For answers like: getting the process input stream in my other project won't work for me. the only way that seems to be working is to use -c option and the command 'exec sys.stdin.read()'.

thank you.

Comment: What does `droidbox.py` look like? If you `print(sys.argv)` in that script, what does it display?

Comment: I would not use the python output inside printf directly, instead use `printf "%s" "$( python ...`

Then, what input should it read, the stdin of the shell script? 

Also, as test, you might assign variables from $1 and $2 and then use the variable names on the call to droidbox.py to avoid someone mangling with the position parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It should work pretty well just the way you've written it. In a stripped down version here's what I get:

the (bash) `test.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
python /tmp/test.py $1 $2
```

the (python) test.py script:

```
import sys
print "in python"
print sys.argv
```

and finally a `shell session`:

```
smassey@hacklabs:/tmp $ ./test.sh hello world
in python
['/tmp/test.py', 'hello', 'world']
```

As you can see, the bash script calls the python script which prints values to `stdout` so they're just as exposed as anything else directed to `stdout`:

```
smassey@hacklabs:/tmp $ ./test.sh hello world | grep python | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
IN PYTHON
```

Answer (score 0):

The argparse module is very helpful as well. This allow you to add custom flags to your program (makes it more convenient to works with from a user's perspective as well).